# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: props.options.map is not a function in react select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react select dropdown in my project and i get this very weired error, i was search the internet and the suggestion was that i have to pass and array of object which i did but still getting the error. when I try to hardcord i just paste in the data i got from fecth it worked without error but when i pass in a state variable which saves the data from fetch it error. how can i solve this error

```
<Select 
      options={states} 
      defaultValue={states[receiverState]}
      placeholder="select state"
      onChange={(e) =>  getAllCities(e)}
      styles={{
      control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
        ...baseStyles,
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? '#fff' : '#fff',
       border:0,
     }),
   }}
  />
```

and below is my data when i log it to the console

```
[
    {
        "label": "California",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "label": "Nevada",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "label": "Atlanta",
        "value": "3"
    }
]
```

wheni hardcode like below it works

```
<Select 
          options={[
                    {
                        "label": "Lagos",
                        "value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Rivers",
                        "value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Ondo",
                        "value": "3"
                    }
                ]} 
          defaultValue={states[receiverState]}
          placeholder="select state"
          onChange={(e) =>  getAllCities(e)}
          styles={{
          control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
            ...baseStyles,
          borderColor: state.isFocused ? '#fff' : '#fff',
           border:0,
         }),
       }}
      />
```

how can i get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the fetch is finished the states are most likely undefined. I assume you have something like this:

```
const [states, setStates] = useState();
```

Try logging the `states` and you will see that it is `undefined`. If you are not passing anything to the `useState` it defaults to `undefined`, in order to solve your issue, you need to provide initial value. Like so:

```
const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
```

This way if you add `console.log({ states })` you will see that it is an empty array at first and then gets populated with the data from the remote api.

Comment: I did pass initial value of [] to the state array and i used useEffect to log it which loged twice before and after data was fected and shows 2 result the first beeing an empty array and the second a fecthed data. after all this try i still get this error

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting states array? Can you log what data are you passing to `setStates`? You might pass `{ data: [] }`, and since it's an object it doesn't have an array methods like `map`. It would be helpful if you would include the data fetching code as well.